# MVC - Render Value and Name Attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, html-helper

Is there a HTML helper in MVC that will render the value of the property with the name attribute. For example,

```
<td><div name="fileName">Hello World<div></td>
```

I'm currently using 'Display for' which just renders the text ...

```
public string FileName{ get; set; }

@Html.DisplayFor(x => Test.FileName)
```

The text is within a form. I'd like to retrieve the value when posting the form data.

Comment: div's don't have or need `name` attributes. `name` is designed for use with form input fields. What are you trying to achieve by adding that to a div?

Comment: so the text is within a form. I'd like to retrieve the value when posting the form data.

Comment: That's a "TextBoxFor" helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The text is within a form. I'd like to retrieve the value when posting
>   the form data.

It won't work like that. The `div` will not be recognised as an input by the browser when you submit the form. Adding a `name` attribute does not make it a valid form field.

If you want to post back the same value (but not have it be editable) then either put the value in a hidden field using  a `HiddenFor` helper (of course can you still use `DisplayFor` at the same time to show the text to the user) or use a read-only textbox.